# Linux find command get all text in the file and print file path

Tags: linux, unix, find

I need to get all the texts in the matching file in the folder. However, at the same time need to get the matching file path as well. How can I get the matching file path as well using the following command.

```
find . -type f -name release.txt | xargs cat
```

Comment: I think this question is probably more suitable for the [Unix Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

try
`find . -type f -name release.txt -exec grep -il {} \; | xargs cat`

Comment: not working , searching like loop

Answer (score 0):

Skip xargs, just do:

```
find . -type f -name release.txt -exec sh -c 'echo "$1"; cat "$1"' _ {} \;
```